# How can I use my UITapGestureRecognizer to enable pinch gesture?

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a function that renders an uploaded photo to the screen that the user can pinch to resize and also pan. My problem is when a second image is loaded I can't pinch to resize the initial image anymore but it can still pan.

I have tried to add the pinch gesture again to the sender in the handleTap function with no luck. I am keeping the pinch gesture on the view rather than the UIImageView so that the user can pinch anywhere on the screen for the image to resize.

How can I use the tapGestureRecogniser to switch between which image is currently enabled for the pinch gesture?

```
//MARK: - Render Art Methods:
    @objc func addPainting(_ notification: Notification) {
        if ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray.count > 0 {
            var artNo = 0
            ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray.count == 1 ? (artNo = 0) : (artNo = ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray.count - 1)
            pickedImageView = UIImageView(image: ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray[artNo].pickedImage)
            pickedImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            pickedImageView.isOpaque = true
            pickedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            pickedImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray[artNo].width ?? 100, height: ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray[artNo].height ?? 80)
            pickedImageView.center = CGPoint(x: userPickedRoom.center.x, y: userPickedRoom.center.y - 50)
            view.addSubview(pickedImageView)
            let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
            pickedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
            let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(_:)))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
            pinchGesture.delegate = self
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
            pickedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            addShadow()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
        guard let gestureView = sender.view else {return}
        gestureView.center = CGPoint(x: gestureView.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureView.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }
    
    @objc func handlePinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.view != nil else { return }
        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
            pickedImageView.transform = (pickedImageView.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale))
            sender.scale = 1.0
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print(sender)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out and thought to post my solution in case anyone else needs it. Not sure if it is the best solution so if anyone has a better solution please share.

My problem was I had no way to access each image so the solution was: as the images are created to store them in an array. I also needed to add a tag to have a value to compare against in the handleTap function. I will post the working code for anyone interested.

```
    var selectedArt = 0
    var artArray = [UIImageView]()

    @objc func addPainting(_ notification: Notification) {
        if ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray.count > 0 {
            var artNo = 0
            ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray.count == 1 ? (artNo = 0) : (artNo = ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray.count - 1)
            pickedImageView = UIImageView(image: ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray[artNo].pickedImage)
            pickedImageView.tag = artNo
            selectedArt = artNo
            pickedImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            pickedImageView.isOpaque = true
            pickedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            pickedImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray[artNo].width ?? 100, height: ArtBrain.artBrain.artArray[artNo].height ?? 80)
            pickedImageView.center = CGPoint(x: userPickedRoom.center.x, y: userPickedRoom.center.y - 50)
            view.addSubview(pickedImageView)
            let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
            pickedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
            let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(_:)))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
            pickedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            artArray.append(pickedImageView)
            addShadow()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handlePinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.view != nil else {return}
        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
            artArray[selectedArt].transform = (artArray[selectedArt].transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale))
            sender.scale = 1.0
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.view != nil {
            selectedArt = sender.view!.tag
        }
    }
```